# Ionic the header disappear because of the keyboard.show() on focus with the textarea

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, viewport

The header disappear when I click in the textarea on the Iphone with the IOS 10.3, my plugin is the basic keyboard from ionic
Is there a solution for this old issue ?
I can't find an answer to solve this issue

Comment: This issues still persist in ionic 4, the scenario is different for me: when there is a toaster in the bottom before toast disappears away I am trying to type in something in the text area and header dissapears right out of the screen, is there a possible way to handle keyboard for input and toaster in the bottom at the same time?